# How to extend the Schema in Mongoose?

Tags: schema, mongoose

I would like to add a static method to the Schema class, how do I do without changing the main Schema class?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the [website](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) documents it:

```
// assign a function to the "statics" object of our animalSchema
 animalSchema.statics.findByName = function (name, cb) {
 this.find({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') }, cb);
}
```